# Show that if B is obtained from A by row operations, then R(A) = R(B).

Tags: linear-algebra

My theory is that span of matrix doesn't change when it is obtained using row operations. And therefore $\text{R}(A) = \text{R}(B)$. But I don't know how to write this

Comment: do you mean column span or row span?

Comment: The rows of $B$ are linear combination of rows of $A$. Can you prove from that?

Comment: Missing context ,can you add some more details?

Comment: You can use two facts to demonstrate this. First notice that row reduction is the same as multiplying to the left for elementary matrices. This means that $A$ and $B$ are equivalent matrices. Then use the fact that rank is a complete invariant for matrix equivalence. Don't hesitate to ask for some explanation.

Comment: What is $R$? The row space, the rank?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_1,...,A_n $ be  rows of A and $B_1,...,B_n$ be rows of B

We know that B is obtained from A which means

$B_1=c_1A_1+...+c_nA_b$

$\vdots =\vdots$

$B_n=c_{n^2-n+1}A_1+....+c_{n^2}A_n $

$Span <A_1,...,A_n>={x_1A_1+...+x_nA_n:x_i \epsilon R \forall i \epsilon N}$

$Span <B_1,...,B_n>={y_1B_1+...+y_nB_n:y_i \epsilon T \forall i\epsilon N}$

But  $y_1B_1+...+y_nB_n=y_1(A_1c_1+...+c_nA_n)+...+y_n(c_{n^2-n+1}A_1+...+c_{n^2}A_n)$

$=(y_1c_1+...+y_nc_{n^2-n+1})A_1+...+(y_1c_n+...+y_nc_{n^2})A_n $ which is linear combination of $A_1,...A_n $ which means span =span

Answer (score 0):

A row operation applied to a matrix $A$ is equivalent to multiplying by an elementary matrix $E$ on the left. Each elementary matrix is invertible, which is equivalent to the fact that each row operation can be 'undone' by another row operation.

Any invertible matrix $B$ retains the rank of $A$ when multiplied by it, $$\mathrm{rank}(BA)=\mathrm{rank}(A)$$ This is because linearly independent vectors $v_i$ (spanning the image of $A$) remain independent as $Bv_i$, since $$\sum_i\alpha_iBv_i=0\Rightarrow B\left(\sum_i\alpha_iv_i\right)=0\Rightarrow \sum_i\alpha_iv_i=B^{-1}0=0\Rightarrow \forall i, \alpha_i=0$$

As a consequence, a sequence of row operations do not change the rank of $A$ $$\mathrm{rank}(E_n\cdots E_1A)=\mathrm{rank}(A)$$